# Arguments against using html as the data carrier with HATEOAS?

Tags: html, hateoas

I started reading up on using HATEOAS for an application and thought that it might be a good idea to use structured HTML for the data as opposed to use for instance json.

The below example:

```
{
    "name": "Alice",
    "avatar": "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7"
    "links": [ {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/customer/1"
    },
    {
        "rel": "up",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/customer"
    }, 
    {
        "rel": "orders",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/customer/1/order"
    }
    ]
}
```

could be rewritten in HTML as:

```html
<html><head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/site-wide-script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site-wide-styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body data-type="customer">
        <div data-attribute="name">Alice</div>
        <div data-attribute="avatar"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" alt="avatar"></div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="http://localhost:8080/customer/1" rel="self">Info</a>
                <a href="http://localhost:8080/customer" rel="up">Customers</a>
                <a href="http://localhost:8080/customer/1/order" rel="customers">Orders</a>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <form method="put">
                    <label>Name<input type="text" name="name"></label>
                    <label>Avatar<input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg"></label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit">
                </form>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <form method="delete">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                </form>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body></html>
```

The above would represent the "customer" along with all the actions that can be taken on this entity with the added benefit of specifying how those actions should be performed.

My idea is to create a very progressive web app that always provides the user with their capabilities and that mainly use the same `site-wide-script.js` and `site-wide-stylesheet.css` to modify how things are displayed in a consistent manner across all views in the UI. The other script and stylesheet could potentially be used to do something very entity specific (e.g. more advanced validation in some cases, or dyamically pulling in sub entities into the same UI).

Essentially this uses the UI as the data carrier and might make building for instance a mobile app more cumbersome...

**Are there any arguments against representing the data in this way when doing HATEOAS aside from the obvious size difference of the responses?**

- Is it invalid according to some RFC?
- Has this been tried somewhere else and failed (it seems most HATEOAS resources use examples with json or xml)?
- Are there data that can not be represented in this manner in a good way?

Answer (score 1):

The most popular implementation of HATEOAS is often cited as the web itself. HTML *is* an implementation of HATEOAS.

So, yes. If you build a HTML-driven best-practice web application you are doing HATEOAS.

Comment: That is interesting way of looking at it. Seems to water down the concept of HATEOAS if it just encompasses all the web. Or do you mean that it only applies for "HTML-driven best-practice web application"?

Comment: Well, I think what are best practices are arguable, but I think it's worth mentioning that HATEOAS is really just "REST as its intended" and HTML + HTTP was always the first application of REST, including the "code on demand" constraint.

Comment: Whether HTML is for you, for this purpose really depends more on your unique use-case and who and what is consuming this data. Is it a good developer experience, i don't know? Maybe? It cannot be argued though that this is 'good HATEOAS' though, because it truly is the OG REST application

Comment: I see what you mean and whether or not is a good developer experience remains to be tested! I'm just gonna try it out on some smaller personal project and see how it goes. The interesting bit for me is if the approach I intend to take can be generalized enough so that as a dev I only have to focus on defining my data model and business logic and have the front-end be generated and consistent (while being aesthetically pleasing too).

Comment: Sounds awesome! If you ever write an article about this, be sure to let me know! (maybe via twitter? https://twitter.com/evertp)

Answer (score 0):

REST and HATEOAS is an architecture style that doesn't even depend on the communication protocol used, thus the underlying media type used to generate a response also doesn't really matter.

However, the key concept should be that all resources should be accessible from a single URI, and the document type you adopt to describe resources should enable clients to discover and transition between application states.  Thus, if you really want to use HTML to describe resources then you should specify your own HTML-based document type, so that clients can be designed to correctly discover and transition between application states.

From the looks of your example, you've already defined a document type, at least implicitly. Therefore, it seems it's just a matter of providing a specification and serve your documents under a dedicated media type (something in the line of `text/emil+html`, for example)

Recommended reading: [REST APIs must be hypertext-driven - Roy Fielding's blog, 2008-10-20](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)